# Suppressing of Entity Framework SQL output to console in Serilog for Azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, serilog

I have an azure function (.net 6, isolated)
I use serilog and want to suppress all SQL output into console.

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s =>
    {
        s.AddLogging(lb =>
        {
            lb.AddSerilog(new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Azure", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command", LogEventLevel.Warning)
                .WriteTo.Sentry(o =>
            {
                // Debug and higher are stored as breadcrumbs (default is Information)
                o.MinimumBreadcrumbLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug;
                // Warning and higher is sent as event (default is Error)
                o.MinimumEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;
                o.Dsn = "https://xxx@yyy.ingest.sentry.io/zzz";
            })
                .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .CreateLogger());
        });
```

But when the azure function operates on database it gives me an SQL output.
in the host.json I have

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Did I miss anything to turn off the Entity Framework information level?

It seems to me that

```
.WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel:LogEventLevel.Warning)
```

doesn't make a difference because when I comment it out, I still received a console output.

Comment: Does it happen in dev environment too? How do you set up your context?

Comment: @GuruStron I don't differentiate dev from non dev context like I do it in Web API projects. I'm even not sure whether it is possible to differentiate it on azure function. Is it?

Comment: AFAIK it should be possible to [develop them locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local).

Comment: @GuruStron I do develop them locally